# Secure file downloads in dotnetnuke

Tags: security, dotnetnuke

I'm relatively new to dotnetnuke and am trying to set up a simple site which will have multiple user groups with their own set of files and then another user that has access to all files.

I'm currently playing with doing this with the "documents" module and hiding the module from all but the everything user and the specific company user. This works fine but the security seems to be just security by obscurity.

If I log in as User A and get access to file A and copy its url. I then log out and log in as user B who can't see that file. If I then put the file url into the browser it seems to download fine.

Can anybody tell me if I am doign something wrong or is there no actual user based security on file downloads? I've tried goign to the actual file manager and making the directories explicitly not viewable to user B (they are secure directories too) but still it persists. Am I missing a permissions option at the file level somewhere or is the security designed to just prevent you finding the right links to the files? I'll admit the links aren't guessable (no sequential ids in the url or anything silly like that) but I'm still a little uncomfortable with the security working like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I *was* doing something wrong. I was referencing a different version of the file which didn't have any permissions attached to it. It seems also that I don't need to have multiple documents modules since if a file doesn't have read permission it will just be hidden in the list.

So to summarise the DNN Documents module *will* do role based security to prevent unauthorised users from downloading the file and from seeing it in the documents view.

Answer (score 1):

[DNN FileManager Module](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Development/ReleaseManagement/Roadmap/FileManager/tabid/625/Default.aspx)

Hi Chris,

Please check out the FileManager module per above link.  You are correct that the current FileManager module does not allow access per user roles.  You might check Snowcovered for possible substitutes?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Will check out snowcovered but had hoped that the built in one did what I wanted withotu having to evaluate third party modules. :)

Answer (score 0):

Documents module provides security for **LinkClick.aspx** urls that are routed to ASP.NET.

If the actual files reside in the file system under the site's root folder, **direct urls** to these files are served and secured by IIS.
To prevent unauthorized access to direct urls you can disable anonymous authentication and set up Basic authentication with NTFS permissions, for example.

If don't want to touch IIS and administer Windows accounts, you can't store the files directly under any publicly available IIS folder. Security at the ASP.NET application-level is implemented using file encryption or storing the files outside the public IIS folders, like in the database. DNN File Manager offers both of these options: secure folders in the file system and secure folders in the database.

There are also 3rd party modules to manage file security and sharing, like [NukeTransfer](http://www.snowcovered.com/snowcovered2/Default.aspx?tabid=242&PackageID=16965).